# Reloading DeckGL HexagonLayer when data array changes/Triggering reload for DeckGL HexagonLayer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deck.gl

I'm using DeckGL with React to display some data on an OpenStreetMap.
I'm planning on implementing some filters to be able to display different views on the data I have.
My main problem is, that I can't figure out how to refresh the data representing layer after filtering the data array.

I saw a bunch of people creating a DeckGL-Object in JavaScript, and then using this, to call `deck.setProps()` but I couldn't figure out how to render this DeckGL-Object by using react.

This is my `app.js`:

```
export default function App({showBorder = false, onTilesLoad = null}) {
  layers = [
    /**
     * TileLayer ist ein Layer aus Open-Streetmap-Tiles (Anzeigen der Karte)
     */
    new TileLayer({
      data: [/*OSM TileServer*/],
      maxRequests: 20,
      pickable: true,
      onViewportLoad: onTilesLoad,
      autoHighlight: showBorder,
      highlightColor: [60, 60, 60, 40],
      minZoom: 0,
      maxZoom: 19,
      tileSize: 512 / devicePixelRatio,
      renderSubLayers: (props) => {
        const {
          bbox: {west, south, east, north}
        } = props.tile;
        return [
          new BitmapLayer(props, {
            data: null,
            image: props.data,
            bounds: [west, south, east, north]
          }),
          showBorder &&
            new PathLayer({
              id: `${props.id}-border`,
              visible: props.visible,
              data: [
                [
                  [west, north],
                  [west, south],
                  [east, south],
                  [east, north],
                  [west, north]
                ]
              ],
              getPath: (d) => d,
              getColor: [255, 0, 0],
              widthMinPixels: 4
            })
        ];
      }
    }),
    new HexagonLayer({
      id: 'hexagon-layer',
      data: /*JsonDataArray*/,
      pickable: true,
      extruded: true,
      radius: 2000,
      elevationRange: [25, 500],
      elevationScale: 200,
      autoHighlight: true,
      opacity: 0.2,
      colorRange: [
        [255, 255, 204],
        [199, 233, 180],
        [127, 205, 187],
        [65, 182, 196],
        [44, 127, 184],
        [37, 52, 148]
      ],
      getElevationHeight: () => 500,
      getPosition: (d) => d.coordinates,
    })
  ];

  return (
    <DeckGL
      layers={layers}
      views={new MapView({repeat: true})}
      initialViewState={INITIAL_VIEW_STATE}
      controller={true}
    />
  );
}
```

Obviously is there a little bit more to my `app.js` but I don't think the missing parts are important since I just wanna know how I can refresh a layer.

I also have a `index.html` but I don't think it's content is really relevant either since it's only use is to call the `App` function to render the layers.

I just can't find out what to do, to cause a reload of the HexagonLayer.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. A good approach is using [DataFilterExtension](https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/extensions/data-filter-extension). GPU-based data
   filtering, go this way if you care about **performance**. For the
   moment [there is a limitation](https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/extensions/data-filter-extension#not-supported) of the extension for
   `HexagonLayer`, but maybe using `GPUGridLayer` can help you in your
   visualization also.

   I.e: let's say you want to filter your qualitative data.
   `filterRange` needs numeric bounds (which defines whether an object
   should be rendered), so you can set your bounds as `[1, 1]` and
   check if some object matches with you current filter condition, if
   matches, `getFilterValue` gets 1, so that object will be rendered,
   otherwise, not rendered:

   ```
    const [filterCondition, setFilter] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        // dispatch some action to set the filter
        setFilter('cities');
    }, []);

    new ScatterplotLayer({
        ...otherProps,
        getFilterValue: object => object.properties.target === filterCondition ? 1 : 0,
        filterRange: [1, 1],
        extensions: [new DataFilterExtension({ filterSize: 1 })],
        updateTriggers: {
            // It's important to tell deck.gl when to update
            getFilterValue: filterCondition
        }
    });
   ```
2. Otherwise updating you `data` array should be enough. That means a
   CPU-based data filtering, if your data is not huge, it's okey.
   Thanks to reactivity should be enough with something like this:

   ```
   const [yourData, setData] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {
       // dispatch some action to set data
       setData([newData]);
   }, []);

   const layers = [
       new HexagonLayer({
           ...otherProps,
           data: yourData
       });
   ];

   return (
       <DeckGL
           ...otherProps,
           layers={layers}
       />
   );
   ```

P.D: `deck.setProps()` is recommended to use in a non-reactive environment